Unify numbering of Theorems (amsmath package) and Exercises (Exsheets package)
I'm quite new to Latex and struggle since a couple of days with a numbering issue I'm having.
I want to write a math script that contains theory (definitions, theorems, lemmas, examples, ...) and Exercises. For the exercises I want to write the solutions right after the Example, but show them in the end of the chapter. The ExSheets package does exactly what I want - the only issue I have is the numbering. It numbers the Exercises and the theory independent and I want the same numbering, i.e. Definition 1.1, Lemma 1.2, Exercice 1.3, Exercise 1.4, ... Solution 1.3, Solution 1.4
Can anybody help how to solve this?
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{exsheets} % used for exercises and solutions

\SetupExSheets{
        counter-format=ch.qu[1]
        ,counter-within=chapter
}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[thm]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Definition}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[thm]{Lemma}

\numberwithin{thm}{chapter} 


% begin document
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{Definition}
    this is a definition
\end{Definition}

\begin{Lemma}
    this is a lemma.
\end{Lemma}

\begin{question}
    this is the first question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    this is the first solution
\end{solution}
\begin{question}
    this is the second question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    this is the second solution
\end{solution}


% section with solutions
\section{solutions}
\printsolutions[chapter]


\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE!

Make \c@question (the internal register for questions) the same as \c@thm.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{exsheets} % used for exercises and solutions

\SetupExSheets{
  counter-format=ch.qu[1],
  counter-within=chapter,
}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Theorem}[thm]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Definition}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[thm]{Lemma}

\numberwithin{thm}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\let\c@question\c@thm
\makeatother


% begin document
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{Definition}
    this is a definition
\end{Definition}

\begin{Lemma}
    this is a lemma.
\end{Lemma}

\begin{question}
    this is the first question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    this is the first solution
\end{solution}
\begin{question}
    this is the second question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
    this is the second solution
\end{solution}

% section with solutions
\section{solutions}
\printsolutions[chapter]

\end{document}



Thanks a lot egreg! That was exactly what I was looking for.
Do you have a link to a documentation or similar, where I can find additional details to this function? I included it in my latex document, it works, and I have a guess that it unifies the counters (which I want) but I'm not familiar with the syntax nor how to potentially use it in a different context going forward.

@Rob I just looked in the package code. You might make a feature request to the author.
